# вопросы по множествам в Python

Tags: python

во время обучения Python наткнулся на не понятную мне сложность.

Задание такое:

Общие числа
На вход программе подаются две строки текста, содержащие числа. Напишите программу, которая выводит все числа в порядке возрастания, которые есть как в первой строке, так и во второй.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подаются две строки текста, содержащие числа, отделенные символом пробела.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести множество чисел, встречающихся в обеих строках.

Теперь сам код который я написал:

```
print(*sorted(set(input().split()) & set(input().split())))
```

Подробнее:

```
myset1 = set(input().split())
myset2 = set(input().split())

myset3 = myset1 & myset2 # intersection()
print(sorted(myset3))
```

входные данные:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Выводит:

1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Почему, вместо сортированного, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 выводит такое?

В первый раз пишу сюда, заранее прошу простить за ошибки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что вы храните не числа, а строки. Ваша задача решается так:

```
myset1 = set(map(int, input().split())) # <---
myset2 = set(map(int, input().split())) # <---

myset3 = myset1 & myset2 # intersection()
print(sorted(myset3))
```

Comment: Благодарю, как раз так и сделал и всё удачно прошло, забыл что были строки, а нужны были числа.

Comment: Да, спасибо, "а ларчик просто открывался".

Answer (score 4):

вы можете отсортировать и строки, просто используйте нужный ключ:

```
print('out: ', *sorted(set(input('nums_1: ').split()) & set(input('nums_2: ').split()), key=int))
#                                                                                       ^^^^^ ключ
'''
nums_1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
nums_2: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
out:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Для меня это пока не понятно, но спасибо в будущем пригодится ))

Answer (score 1):

##### Можно использовать аргумент `key` принимающий функцию, применяемую к элементам последовательности для сравнения. В данном случае целесообразно использовать `int`

```py
myset1 = set(input().split())
myset2 = set(input().split())

myset3 = myset1 & myset2 # intersection()
print(sorted(myset3, key=int))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один однострочник для разнообразия. Не люблю, когда код повторяется, тут без повторения конструкций:

```py
print(*sorted(set.__and__(*(set(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(2)))))
```